# Why is the Ethereum paper called the "yellow paper"?

Tags: history, yellow-paper

I googled this and this does not exist here yet, so

> Why is the Ethereum paper called the "yellow paper"?

Answer (score 14):

***The*** Ethereum paper is the [White Paper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper), originally published by Vitalik towards the end of 2013. (About a month later, in early 2014, Vitalik announced the start of the project.)

Other colours of paper are presumably plays on the fact that the colour white was already taken.

---

The [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) (a technical specification) was written later by Gavin Wood (at least by April 2014 - unsure of the exact date). If you print out the PDF, you'll see it's on a yellow background.

The [Mauve Paper](https://cdn.hackaday.io/files/10879465447136/Mauve%20Paper%20Vitalik.pdf) was published in September 2016 by Vitalik. Again, the background is mauve (which is a pink/purple colour).

The [Polkadot Paper](http://www.the-blockchain.com/docs/Gavin%20Wood%20-%20Polkadot%20-%20%20Vision%20For%20A%20Heterogeneous%20Multi-chain%20Framework.pdf) was published in November 2016 by Gavin Wood. The background of the document is pink with white dots.

---

Other projects have continued this trend. For example, the Melonport white paper is actually their [Green Paper](https://github.com/melonproject/greenpaper)...